# BETWEEN with range including '1' also returns '10'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, between

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour using a BETWEEN predicate in ZF2.
Consider the following code:

```
$ranges = array(
            array(
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 4
            ),
            array(
                'min' => 7,
                'max' => 9
            )
);

$predicates = array();

foreach($ranges as $range){
    // create a new 'Between' predicate and add it to array
    $between = new Predicate\Between('my_field', $range['min'], $range['max']);
    array_push($predicates, $between);
}

// add predicateset
$select->where->addPredicate(
    new Predicate\PredicateSet(
                            $predicates,
                            Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR
                       )
);
```

Now all of this works fine, except when using a range including `1` (eg. `0-2`, `1-5` etc).
In that case the resultset also includes values of `10`

However, this does not happen when I try something like the query below directy on the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

(`my_field` is a `varchar` in this case)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your field is a varchar field, so it's doing a string comparison. '10' is indeed between '0' and '5'.

Comment: @TheVedge: So ZF2 is converting my range values to strings?
eg  `BETWEEN '0' AND '5'` instead of `BETWEEN 0 AND 5`

Comment: Not sure if it's ZF2 or MySQL converting based on connection settings. In general, if you want to compare a string as an integer value (which is not a good idea in the first place since it won't be able to use indexing), you should try to explicitly cast my_field into an into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging through the ZF2 libraries, I found out that the `Between` predicate, always sets the input values to a `TYPE_VALUE`, which basically means the values get wrapped in quotes.

One solution would be to change the `Between` class in the library to use a `TYPE_LITERAL`, but I think its bad practice to mess around with the ZF2 library.

In the end I got it to work by setting a custom specification for the predicate, for which ZF2 provides a method `setSpecification`. This will cast the values back to an integer.

```
//...

    $between = new Predicate\Between('my_field', $range['min'], $range['max']);

    $between->setSpecification('%1$s BETWEEN CAST(%2$s AS UNSIGNED) AND CAST(%3$s AS UNSIGNED)');

//...
```

Maybe not the prettiest solution, but it works for what I need.